# Add new column that is a copy of another that strips diacritics (MSSQL)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column that contains last name, this could contain diacritics. What I want to do is maintain this column, but add a new column to the table that is a copy of the last name column but strips the diacritics.

I found an example that looked like so

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[party]
    ADD [LastNameCleaned] NVARCHAR(200) null AS ([dbo].[party].[lastname] COLLATE LATIN1_GENERAL_100_CI_AI);
```

However this does not work for me within MSSQL it states an error with AS.

Any ideas on how I can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL Server doesn't allow a type for a computed column.  So try this:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[party]
    ADD [LastNameCleaned] AS (lastname COLLATE LATIN1_GENERAL_100_CI_AI);
```

You can persist computed columns and build an index on them:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[party]
    ADD [LastNameCleaned] AS (lastname COLLATE LATIN1_GENERAL_100_CI_AI) persisted;

CREATE INDEX idx_party_LastNameCleaned ON party(LastNameCleaned);
```

Comment: Ah yes that makes sense as you are essentially cloning the existing column so it should just be a copy. Thanks

Comment: Is there anyway to make these indexable when I have a function converting the last name to not have non diacritics . I have seen there is a persisted keyword but it will not work the error it comes back with is. cannot be persisted because the column is non-deterministic.